# Submitting the values of two forms from one submit button

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have created three forms in html the first one is the simple forms and the other's adds table rows dynamically on a button click but I want to save both the form when I press the save button which is on the first form. Is it possible to do it using PHP? I searched Google and found something like jQuery but even that doesn't seems to work can anyone help?
Here is my script:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#submit").click(function() {
        $.post($("#form1").attr("action"), $("#form1").serialize(),
          function() {
        $.post($("#form2").attr("action"), $("#form1").serialize(),
          function() {
            $.post($("#form3").attr("action"), $("#form2").serialize(),
              function() {
                alert('Both forms submitted');
              });
          });
      });
  });
});
</script>

  <table border="1" align="right">
        <tr>
            <td>   
                <input class="cmdsave" type="submit" id="submit" name="save" value="Save" />
            </td>
            <td>
            </td>
            <td>   
                <input class="cmdexit" type="button" onClick="window.history.back()" value="Exit" />
            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>
   </nav>
<body onLoad="document.machine.code.focus()">
 <div id="content">
    <section class="tab" id="home">

    <!--<center><font size="5px" color="#6B6A68"><strong>Customer - Add</strong></font></center>  -->
    <form action="quotation.php" class="general2" align="left" name="quot" id="form1" method="POST">
                    <input type="hidden" name="vouchno" value="<?php echo ($addflag == 0) ? $get['vouchno'] : ""; ?>">
                <table border="0px" width="100%">  
                    <tr>
                        <td><br/></td>
                    </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td width="200px" align="right"><label for=""><font color="0099FF" size="3px">Quotation No.</font><span></span></label></td>
                    <td align="left"><input type="text" size="6" maxlength="6" id="code" maxlength="6" name="code" value="<?php echo ($addflag == 0) ? $get['code'] : ""; ?>" class="form-input-code"  />
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<label for=""><font color="0099FF" size="3px"> Date </font><span></span></label><input type="date" size="80" name="oildate" value="<?php echo ($addflag == 0) ? $get['vouchdt'] : $today; ?>"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td width="200px" align="right"><label for=""><font color="0099FF" size="3px">Party Name </font><span></span></label></td>
                    <td align="left"><select data-placeholder="Party" style="width:332px;" name="cmbparty" class="chzn-select-deselect" onChange="showyear('party.php?code='+this.value);">
                              <option value="<?php echo ($addflag == 0) ? $get['party'] : ""; ?>"><?php echo ($addflag == 0) ? $get['party'] : ""; ?></option>
                           <?php
                             $mown = mysql_query("SELECT accode, `name` FROM accmast WHERE grpcode='010'") or die(mysql_error());
                              while($trow = mysql_fetch_array($mown)){
                                     echo "<option value=$trow[accode]>$trow[name]</option>";
                                    }
                            ?>
                        </select></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td colspan="9">
                      <div id="parthint" style=""></div>
                    </td>  
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td width="200px" align="right"><label for=""><font color="" size="3px">Ref. No. </font><span></span></label></td>
                    <td align="left"><input type="text" id="refno" size="20" maxlength="20"  name="refno" value="<?php echo ($addflag == 0) ? $get['refno'] : ""; ?>" class="form-input-c20"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td width="200px" align="right"><label for=""><font color="" size="3px">Kindly Attn. </font><span></span></label></td>
                    <td align="left"><input type="text" id="refno" size="20" maxlength="80"  name="attn" value="<?php echo ($addflag == 0) ? $get['attn'] : ""; ?>" class="form-input-add"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td width="200px" align="right"><label for=""><font color="" size="3px">Subject. </font><span></span></label></td>
                    <td align="left"><textarea name="subject" rows="3" cols="70" class="form-input-textarea"><?php echo ($addflag == 0) ? $get['subject'] : ""; ?></textarea></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td colspan="9">
                        <hr />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td width="200px" align="right"><label for=""><font color="0099FF" size="3px">Dear Sir / Madam, </font><span></span></label></td>
                  <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td align="left"><textarea name="msg" cols="70" class="form-input-textareaxl"><?php echo ($addflag == 0) ? $get['message'] : ""; ?></textarea></td>

                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td width="200px" align="right"><label for=""><font color="0099FF" size="3px">Status</font><span></span></label></td>
                    <td align="left"><select data-placeholder="Status" style="width:332px;" name="cmbstatus" class="chzn-select-deselect">
                              <option value="<?php echo ($addflag == 0) ? $get['status'] : ""; ?>"><?php echo ($addflag == 0) ? $get['status'] : ""; ?></option>
                              <option value="<?php echo ($addflag == 0) ? $get['status'] : "Pending"; ?>"><?php echo ($addflag == 0) ? $get['status'] : "Pending"; ?></option>
                              <option value="<?php echo ($addflag == 0) ? $get['status'] : "Approved"; ?>"><?php echo ($addflag == 0) ? $get['status'] : "Approved"; ?></option>
                              <option value="<?php echo ($addflag == 0) ? $get['status'] : "Rejected"; ?>"><?php echo ($addflag == 0) ? $get['status'] : "Rejected"; ?></option>

                        </select></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td width="200px" align="right"><label for=""><font color="" size="3px">Remarks. </font><span></span></label></td>
                    <td align="left"><textarea name="rem" rows="3" cols="70" class="form-input-textarea"><?php echo ($addflag == 0) ? $get['subject'] : ""; ?></textarea></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td><br/></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td></td><td>
                       </td>

                    <td>
                </tr>
            </table>

    </form>
        </section>
     <section class="tab" id="company"></section>

    <section class="tab" id="portfolio">

        <form action="quotation.php" class="general2" align="left" name="quot2" id="form2" method="POST">

                <table border="1px" width="90%" id="data">
                  <tr>
                      <td><br /></td>
                  </tr>
                                    <tr>
                      <td><br /></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td width="130px" align="center"><label for=""><font color="#0099FF" size="3px">Order</font><span></span></label></td>
                     <td width="130px" align="center"><label for=""><font color="#0099FF" size="3px">Sr No.</font><span></span></label></td>
                     <td width="580px" align="center"><label for=""><font color="#0099FF" size="3px">Description</font><span></span></label></td>
                     <td width="130px" align="center"><label for=""><font color="#0099FF" size="3px">Unit</font><span></span></label></td>
                     <td width="130px" align="center"><label for=""><font color="#0099FF" size="3px">Rate</font><span></span></label></td>
                  </tr>
                  <?php if($addflag==0){
                          $qry = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  `quotdtl` WHERE vouchno='$getvouch'") or die(mysql_error());

                          $ctr = 0;    
                          while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($qry)) {
                                 echo "<td align=\"center\"><input type=\"text\" size=\"6\" maxlength=\"6\" id=\"code\" maxlength=\"6\" name=\"ord_$ctr\" value=\"$row[orderby]\" class=\"form-input-oth\"  /></td>";     
                                 echo "<td align=\"center\"><input type=\"text\" size=\"6\" maxlength=\"6\" id=\"code\" maxlength=\"6\" name=\"srno_$ctr\" value=\"$row[srno]\" class=\"form-input-oth\"  /></td>";
                                 echo "<td align=\"center\"><textarea name=\"descrip_1\" cols=\"70\" class=\"form-input-textarea\">$row[descrip]</textarea></td>";
                                 echo "<td align=\"center\"><input type=\"text\" size=\"6\" maxlength=\"9\" id=\"code\" maxlength=\"6\" name=\"unit_$ctr\" value=\"$row[unit]\" class=\"form-input-rate\"/></td> ";
                                 echo "<td align=\"center\"><input type=\"text\" size=\"6\" maxlength=\"9\" id=\"code\" maxlength=\"6\" name=\"rate_$ctr\" value=\"$row[rate]\" class=\"form-input-rate\"  /></td>";

                                $ctr++; 
                          }
                        }else{                     
                     ?> 
                  <tr>
                    <td align="center"><input type="text" size="6" maxlength="6" id="code" maxlength="6" name="ord_1" value="" class="form-input-oth"  /></td> 
                    <td align="center"><input type="text" size="6" maxlength="6" id="code" maxlength="6" name="srno_1" value="" class="form-input-oth"  /></td> 
                    <td align="center"><textarea name="descrip_1" cols="20" class="form-input-textarea"></textarea></td>
                    <td align="center"><input type="text" size="6" maxlength="9" id="code" maxlength="6" name="unit_1" value="" class="form-input-rate"  /></td> 
                    <td align="center"><input type="text" size="6" maxlength="9" id="code" maxlength="6" name="rate_1" value="" class="form-input-rate"  /></td> 
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td align="center"><input type="text" size="6" maxlength="6" id="code" maxlength="6" name="ord_2" value="" class="form-input-oth"  /></td> 
                    <td align="center"><input type="text" size="6" maxlength="6" id="code" maxlength="6" name="srno_2" value="" class="form-input-oth"  /></td> 
                    <td align="center"><textarea name="descrip_2" cols="20" class="form-input-textarea"></textarea></td>
                    <td align="center"><input type="text" size="6" maxlength="9" id="code" maxlength="6" name="unit_2" value="" class="form-input-rate"  /></td> 
                    <td align="center"><input type="text" size="6" maxlength="9" id="code" maxlength="6" name="rate_2" value="" class="form-input-rate"  /></td> 
                  </tr>
                   <tr>
                    <td align="center"><input type="text" size="6" maxlength="6" id="code" maxlength="6" name="ord_3" value="" class="form-input-oth"  /></td> 
                    <td align="center"><input type="text" size="6" maxlength="6" id="code" maxlength="6" name="srno_3" value="" class="form-input-oth"  /></td> 
                    <td align="center"><textarea name="descrip_3" cols="20" class="form-input-textarea"></textarea></td>
                    <td align="center"><input type="text" size="6" maxlength="9" id="code" maxlength="6" name="unit_3" value="" class="form-input-rate"  /></td> 
                    <td align="center"><input type="text" size="6" maxlength="9" id="code" maxlength="6" name="rate_3" value="" class="form-input-rate"  /></td> 
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td align="center"><input type="text" size="6" maxlength="6" id="code" maxlength="6" name="ord_4" value="" class="form-input-oth"  /></td> 
                    <td align="center"><input type="text" size="6" maxlength="6" id="code" maxlength="6" name="srno_4" value="" class="form-input-oth"  /></td> 
                    <td align="center"><textarea name="descrip_4" cols="20" class="form-input-textarea"></textarea></td>
                    <td align="center"><input type="text" size="6" maxlength="9" id="code" maxlength="6" name="unit_4" value="" class="form-input-rate"  /></td> 
                    <td align="center"><input type="text" size="6" maxlength="9" id="code" maxlength="6" name="rate_4" value="" class="form-input-rate"  /></td> 
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td align="center"><input type="text" size="6" maxlength="6" id="code" maxlength="6" name="ord_5" value="" class="form-input-oth"  /></td> 
                    <td align="center"><input type="text" size="6" maxlength="6" id="code" maxlength="6" name="srno_5" value="" class="form-input-oth"  /></td> 
                    <td align="center"><textarea name="descrip_5" cols="20" class="form-input-textarea"></textarea></td>
                    <td align="center"><input type="text" size="6" maxlength="9" id="code" maxlength="6" name="unit_5" value="" class="form-input-rate"  /></td> 
                    <td align="center"><input type="text" size="6" maxlength="9" id="code" maxlength="6" name="rate_5" value="" class="form-input-rate"  /></td> 
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td align="center"><input type="text" size="6" maxlength="6" id="code" maxlength="6" name="ord_6" value="" class="form-input-oth"  /></td> 
                    <td align="center"><input type="text" size="6" maxlength="6" id="code" maxlength="6" name="srno_6" value="" class="form-input-oth"  /></td> 
                    <td align="center"><textarea name="descrip_6" cols="20" class="form-input-textarea"></textarea></td>
                    <td align="center"><input type="text" size="6" maxlength="9" id="code" maxlength="6" name="unit_6" value="" class="form-input-rate"  /></td> 
                    <td align="center"><input type="text" size="6" maxlength="9" id="code" maxlength="6" name="rate_6" value="" class="form-input-rate"  /></td> 
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td align="center"><input type="text" size="6" maxlength="6" id="code" maxlength="6" name="ord_7" value="" class="form-input-oth"  /></td> 
                    <td align="center"><input type="text" size="6" maxlength="6" id="code" maxlength="6" name="srno_7" value="" class="form-input-oth"  /></td> 
                    <td align="center"><textarea name="descrip_7" cols="20" class="form-input-textarea"></textarea></td>
                    <td align="center"><input type="text" size="6" maxlength="9" id="code" maxlength="6" name="unit_7" value="" class="form-input-rate"  /></td> 
                    <td align="center"><input type="text" size="6" maxlength="9" id="code" maxlength="6" name="rate_7" value="" class="form-input-rate"  /></td> 
                  </tr>
                  <?php }?>
            </table>

                         &nbsp;<input type="button" id="addnew" class="classname" name="addnew" value="+" /> 
                          <input type="hidden" id="items" name="items" value="<?php echo ($addflag == 0) ? $ctr : 7; ?>" />                 
    </form>
      </section> 
      <section class="tab" id="contact">

        <form action="quotation.php" class="general2" align="left" name="quot2" id="form3" method="POST">

                <table border="1px" width="90%" id="data2">
                  <tr>
                     <td><br /></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td width="" align="left"><label for=""><font color="#0099FF" size="3px">Notes,</font><span></span></label></td>
                     <td></td><td></td>
                  </tr>
                                    <?php if($addflag==0){
                          $qry = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  `quotnotes` WHERE vouchno='$getvouch'") or die(mysql_error());

                          $mctr = 0;    
                          while ($rownote = mysql_fetch_array($qry)) {
                                 echo "<td align=\"left\"><textarea name=\"note_1\" cols=\"80\" class=\"form-input-textareaxxl\">$rownote[notes]</textarea></td>";

                                $mctr++; 
                          }
                        }else{                     
                     ?>
                  <tr></tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td align="left"><textarea name="note_1" cols="80" class="form-input-textareaxxl"></textarea></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td align="left"><textarea name="note_2" cols="80" class="form-input-textareaxxl"></textarea></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td align="left"><textarea name="note_3" cols="80" class="form-input-textareaxxl"></textarea></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td align="left"><textarea name="note_4" cols="80" class="form-input-textareaxxl"></textarea></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td align="left"><textarea name="note_5" cols="80" class="form-input-textareaxxl"></textarea></td>
                  </tr>
                 <?php }?>
            </table>

                         &nbsp;<input type="button" id="addnew2" class="classname" name="addnew" value="+" /> 
                          <input type="hidden" id="h" name="h" value="<?php echo ($addflag == 0) ? $mctr : 5; ?>" />                 
    </form>
```

Comment: Please show us your HTML code

Comment: check http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/

Comment: Please show full code with your forms

Comment: can you try to add a return false; inside your function cal of button click

Comment: i have posted my full code can anyone help in showing that how can i save the values ?

Comment: Have you got "Both forms submitted" alert ???

Comment: Exactly, what's not working then?

Comment: the values are note being saved into my database

Comment: have you checked if the data reaches your script? With firebug or chrome developers tools? Or logging a **print_r($_POST,true);**

Comment: sir i am new to web development so i dnt have much knowledge abt it

Comment: use **chrome** as browser: right click on your page and select last entry (should be something like **inspect element**). It shoul open a tab below. Click on **Network** tab, reload the page (F5), click your submit button. Now in the list you should see all elements called. click on your forms (quotation.php).In the **header** sub you can see wich field are sended. On the **Preview** you can see the output of your script. SO... you can use simple **echo** instruction to print you query and your values to emprove debugging

Comment: thnkx sir i can see my data in that header sub but can u help in shwoing that how can i save my data in database?

Comment: too vague as a question, continue digging/debugging and post the code relative to the query wich is not working as expected

Comment: i tried going through my code my the values are not getting saved

Comment: Show more efforts, your request must be more specific. Try to echo your sql just before execution to verify its all right. Place some echo in your code to track the execution (to ensure that the program reaches your DB instructions). If you are not proficient with debugging tools (and you aren't able to see the echo) you may convert POST to GET and try call your page directly (quotation.php?param=xx&param=xy...). There are many things you can try. When you have detected the code that behaves incorrectly post it here

Comment: sir i have the save part written inside if(isset($_POST["submit])){ the save part is wriiten here} and i think the submit part is not working as u told tried to echo the query but the echo is not working

Comment: post here your code inside if(isset($_POST.... {}

Answer (score 0):

If I understood what you want, there is an error in second post call: **form1** should be **form2**, in the third **form2** should be **form3**
try to place an alert before every post to debug more efficiently. This will send every form in sequence 1-2-3.

```
   <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#submit").click(function(event) {
              alert('send 1st form');
            $.post($("#form1").attr("action"), $("#form1").serialize(),
              function() {
              alert('send 2nd form');
            $.post($("#form2").attr("action"), $("#form2").serialize(),
              function() {
              alert('send 3th form');
                $.post($("#form3").attr("action"), $("#form3").serialize(),
                  function() {
                    alert('Both forms submitted');
                  });
              });
          });
          event.preventDefault();
      });

    });
    </script>
```

EDIT: added event.preventDefault (thanks to Akam)

Comment: That mistake does not affect ajax cal,

Comment: where is `event.preventDefault()`?

Comment: no, but it affects the data sent. You didn't mentioned what's is not working. Notice that if you have an error with a form, the calling sequence will interrupted. Try using chrome inspection or firebug to check the calls